# What does "take a steam" mean?

Tags: meaning, american-english

I have come across in the TV show *Friends*. Here is the context:

> Ross: Look, this is just a little too familiar, okay? For like, for
>   like six months before Carol and I spilt up, all I heard was: "My
>   friend Susan is so smart. My friend Susan is so funny. My friend Susan
>   is so great."
>
> Chandler: You actually think that something can happen between Emily
>   and Susan?
>
> Ross: Hey, they’re going to the gym together! Two women! Stretching!
>   Y’know they-they **take a steam** together! Things get a little
>   playful—didn’t you see *Personal Best*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A 'steam' probably means a steam bath or sauna, where people are undressed. Ross has a lascivious imagination. 'Personal Best' is a 1982 movie in which two women athletes have a gay affair, and which features nudity in a sauna. The *New York Times* called that section 'horsing around in the steam room', and said, of the film, "Unless you're fascinated by all of the prettified slow-motion footage of Chris, Tory and the other women athletes, your eye is likely to wander to your watch long before the end."

Comment: Not probably, for sure.